# Emacs default saving directory criterion

Tags: emacs, directory, default, dired

My question isn't about configuring emacs. It is about understanding its default behavior, since I'm new to it.

I've noticed that when I save a file with `C-x C-s` sometimes it saves 
the file on my root user directory (`~`). However, sometimes emacs 
writes my files under `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/info/`.
This is very troublesome, cause I can't reach that directory from within 
the Finder for whatever reason (in `\applications` is only the emacs app, I can't reach its subdirectories).

It is also very troublesome to open within emacs itself since I have to click `Open File` from its GUI in order to land on the aforementioned directory.

Why does Emacs sometimes saves on root and sometimes on `\application`?
May it be because of the mode in which I `C-x C-s`?

Comment: The default directory for saving to is the value of variable `default-directory`. That changes when you use a command (such as `dired` or `cd`) that changes to a different directory. Pay attention to the commands (keys) you use, so you can see which ones are placing you in a different directory (i.e., changing `default-directory`). What do you mean by "the mode in which" you use `C-x C-s`? Show a step-by-step recipe of what you are doing, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew. Thanks in advance. I really am a novice, so I don't use `dired` or `cd` or know how to configure init files. As for now,  I just visit files using `C-x C-f` and save them  with `C-x C-s`. The only other featureI use is  `org-mode` to make `TODO` lists. What I mean by the mode in which I `C-x C-s` is that I don't know whether my `default-directory` (thanks for the term) changes when I switch between `fundamental-mode` and `org-mode`. However, I will check the documentation for the keywords you gave me. That will be a good start.

Comment: `default-directory` changes when you use commands like `dired` or `cd`. It also changes when you visit a file (e.g. `C-x C-f`) in a different directory. The `default-directory` of a file's buffer is the file's directory (unless you somehow change it afterward, e.g. using `cd`).